# Bound for orbital integrals

Tags: nt.number-theory, automorphic-forms, trace-formula

Let $F$ be a number field, and $G$ be the group of units of a quaternion algebra $D$ over $F$. At a certain ramified place $v$, for $\gamma_v \in G(F_v)$, could we bound the orbital integral
$$\mathcal{O}_{\gamma_v}(MC(\pi_v)) = \int_{G_{\gamma_v}(F_v) \backslash G(F_v)} MC(\pi_v)(u^{-1}\gamma_v u) \mathrm{d}u$$

where $MC(\pi_v)$ is the matrix coefficient attached to $\pi_v$? I am seeking for a bound in terms of the Plancherel measure of $\pi_v$.

Comment: Can you please define $\mathcal{O}_{\gamma_v}(MC(\pi_v))$? I am not familiar with the notations.

Comment: @SubhajitJana, the definition is the right-hand side of the equality.

Comment: This is just a remark. If $\pi_\nu$ is supercuspidal and $\gamma_\nu$ is a regular elliptic element of $G(F_\nu )$ then the RHS is the value of the Harish-Chandra character of $\pi_\nu$ at $\gamma_\nu$. So in that case you're trying to bound the character of $\pi_\nu$ in terms of the Plancherel measure.

Comment: @PaulBroussous Indeed, however is there something standard to do that? I can think of character formulas to bound in general (Weyl's character formula for instance, at archimedean places for instance), but without using $\pi_v$ and making its Plancherel measure appear